# Folder metadata displaying ID instead of folder Name

Tags: oracle-ucm

I am new to Oracle UCM(already hate it) and I have this bug on the standart "Content information" page when displaying "Folder" meta - instead of DCOLLECTIONNAME I get DCOLLECTIONID from COLLECTIONS table. Now we have two versions of UCM installed on different servers, one with our custom module and one without it, you can guess which one works fine :-) I checked settings in admin aplet / Configuration manager and they are the same on both servers, so my next thought was there must be some problem with page template(I found some function named getCollectionPathFromID somewhere which does exactly what I need but dont know where to put it to make it work). Can anyone point me to the right direction? I found some template called std_page.htm but it contains realy huge amount of code... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What specific versions of WebCenter Content are you using? Are the two instances on the exact same version? You can find this information on the Configuration for *instance name* page.

How are you trying to view the data?

Are you calling &IsSoap=1 or &IsJava=1? Or are you meaning the display of the folder name/path on the page is showing dCollectionID?

I assume that based on dCollectionID you are using the Folders_g (Contribution Folders) component and not [FrameworkFolders](http://jonathanhult.com/blog/2012/10/11g-folders-organized-optimized-modernized/).

Can you provide a link to download your custom component? It sounds like this may be the culprate.